# MySQL loops in a single line code

Tags: mysql

I need a loop command that can fit in one line of code!

I found that i can use

```
CASE TRUE WHEN TRUE THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

The 'CASE' is possible to be written in one line of code unlike 'if' statement.

But what about loops? 'while' or 'for' or anything.

How can i put a loop that returns TRUE or FALSE after the "ELSE" command in the "CASE" above so it can still be valid and be only one line of code?

Comment: (1) Why would it need to be single line; (2) if you actually mean in a single query, then you cannot use loops and it doesn't really make sense to do so anyway.

Comment: Try using stored procedures. This is way too much to ask of the humble `SELECT` statement.

Comment: i need it to be in a single line so I can send it through URL .. as i can not send multiple lines through GET method, and I've tried the urlencode method with %0D to add lines .. but didnt work !

Comment: What do you mean by a loop that returns true or false? A loop is for repeating something, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: MySQL doesn't care about line breaks, all whitespace is equivalent in queries.

Comment: @Barmar if it really doesnt .. then why i cant write an IF statement in one line !!!

Comment: @NuuLL I don't know, why can't you? It uses `;` as the statement separator, not newlines. Note that `IF` statements only exist in stored procedures, not SQL queries. In queries, you have to use the `IF()` function.

Comment: `IF TRUE THEN SET @var = TRUE; ELSE SET @var = FALSE; END IF;` should work